# Вызов функции VB из JavaScript и обновление option'ов тега select без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

На странице в Dive есть 10 элементов select. При изменении значения одного из них все нижестоящие должны подгрузить новые списки для выбора (на каждый select создает новый запрос к базе на sql). Натолкните на мысль, как это сделать?

Comment: А что у вас странички генерирует? Если это ASP.NET, то ASP.NET AJAX либо сделать веб-сервис (.asmx) и вызывать его из JavaScript.

Comment: Да, asp.net. Можете дать ссылку на материалы? Желательно, что коротко и максимально просто))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал, наконец, при помощи коллег то, что хотел.
Попробую описать всё это:
1) Т.к. мне нужно было вывести изначально заполненные элементы, я вместо Select на страницу добавил элементы asp:DropDownList и заполнил их в CodeBehind страницы.

```
  Public  Sub Area_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Area.Load //Пример для элемента с ID = Area
    Area.Items.Clear() //очищаем список
    Dim li As ListItem = New ListItem("Text", "caption") //создаем переменную типа ListItem, куда передаем два значения: 1 - текст, который будет отображаться, 2 - value этого элемента списка 
        If NeedSelected() Then // если нужно сразу загрузить список с уже выбранным элементом
            li.Selected = True
        End If
        Area.Items.Add(li) // добавляем элемент списка на страницу
End Sub
```

2) Далее в js скрипте добавил функции, обрабатывающие события onchange, которые вызывают метод с сервера через PageMethods.

```
function Page_Init(sender) {
                var Area = $get('<%=Area.ClientID %>');
                $addHandler(Area, 'change', Area_changed);
            }

            function Area_changed(evt) {
                PageMethods.SetBuilding(evt.target.selectedIndex, Building_Success, Building_Failure);
            }

            function Building_Success(results) {
                if (results) {
                   // код будет ниже
                }
                else
                    alert("An unexpected error occurred");
            }

            function Building_Failure(error) {
                if (error) {
                    alert(error.get_message());
                }
                else
                    alert("An unexpeceted error occurred");
            }
```

При этом, чтоб вызвать PageMethod, вам на страницу нужно добавить ScriptManager с атрибутом EnablePageMethods="true"

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

3) В CodeBehing страницы написал функцию возвращающую массив элементов

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function SetBuilding(ByVal selectedIndex As Integer)
  // Ваш код
    Return arrayToReturn
End Function
```

4) В function Building_Success в js-скрипте пишу код, обрабатывающий массив и заполняющий список Building

```
function Building_Success(results) {
                if (results) {
                   var ddl = $get('Building'); // забираю нужный мне элемент по ID
                        ddl.options.length = 0; // очищаю его
                        for (item in results) { // т.к. возвращаю с сервера массив объектов, то пробегаю по всем его элементам
                            ddl.options[ddl.options.length]
                                  = new Option(results[item].caption, results[item].ID); // caption и ID - это свойства объектов(элементов массива)
                        }
                }
                else
                    alert("An unexpected error occurred");
            }
```

5) Долго и упорно танцевал с бубном, т.к. у меня в совокупности 10 списков)

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо на каждый `select` повесить обработчик `onchange`. Когда один из обработчиков срабатывает, то следует проверить значения всех элементов (ну или тех, что нужны) и послать соответстующий запрос к серверу.

На сервере необходимо реализовать логику, которая будет по запросу выбирать из БД нужную инфу и отправлять клиенту, например в формате JSON.

Когда инфа пришла, просто JS'ом генерируем новую разметку  (набор `<option>` в данном случае) и вставляем ее куда следует.

Можно генерацию разметки возложить на сервер, то есть сразу придет html, а не JSON. Тогда ответ сервера просто вставляем в нужное место.

Конкретная реализация может широко варьироваться, но суть примерно одинаковая.

Comment: Первую часть я примерно знаю, как реализовать, т.е., что я передам значения на сервер, там выберу нужные мне значения из БД по запросу. А вот как удалить старые option'ы и вставить новые именно в нужное место в разметке? Т.е., как мне передать обратно на клиент данные?

Comment: @Anthony_L Ну можно пользоваться jQuery чтобы облегчить жизнь себе в плане выбора элементов и вставки новых значений. А если через чистый JS, то тут например есть свойство `innerHTML` (хотя есть и иные варианты работы с DOM)  у элемента, то есть можно его полностью заменять в случае с `select` новой разметкой, поиск элемента на странице осуществляется например через `document.querySelectorAll` или `document.getElementById`. Что касается сервера - то в VB я не силен, хотя скажу вам, что данные передаются также как и html при загрузке, то есть точно также "выводите разметку в браузер"

Comment: Мне не принципиально, делать на чистом js, или на jquery. Пока надо просто сделать, чтоб работало)
Если я через PageMethods.CalledMethod буду вызывать метод на сервере, то он мне должен бы возвратить строку, в которой я сформирую разметку на сервере, так? а innerHTML заменяет разметку внутри тега? Т.е. потом я просто эту возвращенную строку пишу в innerHTML и всё?)

И у меня тогда имя метода будет CalledMethods, а храниться он должен в codebehind этой страницы?... Взял это отсюда: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread165127.html
Если разбираетесь, объясните, плз)

Comment: @Anthony_L Не работал с ASP.NET,но из того кода, как я понял, идея ваша верна. Правда видимо вы не понимаете механизма работы всей системы. Да, попытайтесь просто получить любую строку от сервера и вставить ее в innerHTML. Поясню - PageMethods это видимо список JS функций которые просто посылают спец запрос к серверу, где выполняется одноименная функция на C# или VB, которая возвращает данные (строку). Почитайте про XMLHttpRequest в JS и про Ajax запросы,обязательно. Советую книгу Флэнагана "JavaScript. Подробное руководство". или хотя бы на https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest